# R: Compare an element of a single triplet matrix (slam)

Tags: r, matrix, element

The documentation of the slam package for R states:
"Currently implemented operations include the addition, subtraction, multiplication and division of compatible simple triplet matrices, as well as the multiplication and division of a simple triplet matrix and a vector. Comparisons of the elements of a simple triplet matrices with a number are also provided."
But theres nowhere stated how to use this implementation, i wonder how to compare a single element of a simple triplet matrix, when i use

```
matrix[i,j] > 0
```

i get an error cause matrix[i,j] is an object of class 1x1 simple triplet matrix and it's also not possible to coerce it to integer, so how do u compare an element to a single number? i currently use sum(dtm[i,j]) and thats a bit silly but works at least ...

Comment: can you dput your matrix?

Comment: Lets just take the example from the documentation:  
matrix <- simple_triplet_matrix(c(1,4),c(1,2),c(1,2))
Anything like if(matrix[1,1]>0){xyz<-1} will produce an error:
"Error in if (matrix[1, 1] > 0) { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (matrix[1, 1] > 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"